# Nginx Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I am currently trying to get my Nginx+Mysql+Wordpress work on Fedora 18 x64.

Did the following manual http://www.tecmint.com/install-wordpress-using-lamp-or-lemp-on-rhel-centos-fedora/ but nothing seems to work.

Default Nginx greeting is still displayed at localhost:80.

Should i provide some configuration files as examples?

Please help i am really lost. Google'd everything, reading official Nginx manuals atm.

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /run/nginx.pid;


events {
worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
include       /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
include       mime.types;

default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /srv/www/wordpress/public_html;
        index  index.php index.html;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
    #
    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /40x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#    listen       8000;
#    listen       somename:8080;
#    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#    listen       443;
#    server_name  localhost;

#    ssl                  on;
#    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
#    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

#    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

#    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
#    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}

}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post with the nginx config for your wordpress site?

Comment: I haven't really touched nginx.conf file since it is not mentioned in the manual.

Comment: I just realized, should i first do this http://www.tecmint.com/install-lemp-linux-nginx-mysql-php-on-rhel-centos-5-6-fedora-12-17/ guide and then jump on the one i linked in the main post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is my nginx config for one of my Wordpress sites, minus the domain name and IP address, of course...  I built this one using many references online, and it seems to work pretty well.

```
server {
  listen <ip-address>;
  server_name domain.com;
  rewrite ^(.*) $scheme://www.domain.com$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
  listen <ip-address>;
  server_name www.domain.com; 
  root   /www/domain.com/public_html;

  access_log /www/domain.com/logs/access.log;
  error_log /www/domain.com/logs/error.log;

  location = /favicon.ico {
  log_not_found off;
  access_log off;
  }

  location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }

  location / {
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    if ($uri !~ "^/images/") {
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.socket;
    }
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /www/domain.com/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
  }

  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time gonna try it tomorrow. Cheers.

Comment: Great!  If it doesn't work, feel free to message me or post back here and we'll keep working through it. :)