# Nginx+Wordpress+Rails with wp as a subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, wordpress, nginx

I have this environment almost working, but permalinks and images are not working.

My site is deployed in /var/www/staging-site/current/public;
My Wordpress blog is deployed in /var/deployer/www/blog;

```
http {
   server {
        listen  80;
        server_name www.mysite.com;
        access_log  logs/nosubdomain.access.log;
        return 301 $scheme://mysite.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  mysite.com *.mysite.com;
        #charset koi8-r;

        access_log  logs/subdomain.access.log;
        root /var/www/staging-site/current/public;


        location / {
            passenger_enabled on;
            rails_env staging;
                root /var/www/staging-site/current/public;
        }

        location /blog/ {
           root          /home/deployer/www;
           fastcgi_index  index.php;

           if (!-e $request_filename) {
             rewrite  ^(.*)$  /blog/index.php?q=$1  last;
           }
           fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    /home/deployer/www$fastcgi_script_name;
           fastcgi_pass   localhost:9000;  # port to FastCGI
           break;
        }

        location ~* ^/assets/{
                root /var/www/staging-site/current/public;
                expires max;
                add_header Cache-Control public;
                break;
        }
}
```

I want www.mysite.com to show my site, and www.mysite.com/blog to show wordpress blog. It works, but the links doesnt work. For example http://mysite.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/bname-268x300.jpg&w=150&h=150&zc=1&q=90 doesnt show the image, that is there, it shows the root of the blog.

Any help?

Comment: Silly suggestion, but try removing the trailing slash from your blog location (and assets too, but try blog first). I'm also not sure that the rewrite rule is correct for `/blog/index.php`. Try replacing the whole if block with `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;`

Comment: Whats the emoticon for vomiting? Wordpress nested in a rails app, your server should be burned at the stake for heresy.

Comment: my client should be burned at the stake for the heresy, i am just the developer

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: yes, but it didnt work. Maybe I did something wrong. I finally solved by moving blog to a subdomain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comments regarding the trailing slash from your URIs and changing the attributes on `try_files`...

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860932/nginx-wordpress/14861286#14861286) is my nginx config for my WordPress blog.  Parts of this can be plugged into any location block within an nginx config.

Let me know if this doesn't help.